# How to block UIAppearance proxy for some control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

I set custom appearance to some of my UI classes.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:someColor];
...
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:someImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

So when i create `UIBarButtonItem's` or `UINavigationBar's` objects in my application they will have defined appearance.

But if want some object to have standart appearance(Not to use defined by proxy), I need to set all it's properties to default values manually.

*So the quesion is:* Is there any way to block using `UIAppearance` for some object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Its probably not 100% what you want to do but you could use appearanceWhenContainedIn.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolbar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

This way you can control the behavior to a certain degree.

Setting the properties to nil will use the default appearance: 
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:nil];

Comment: Read the question please, i understand that i can manually change properties to default, but if my UIAppearance proxy changes a lot of values, it is stupid to revert all the properties one by one. So i ask how to block this proxy for some UI control